# Does Proguard remove comments from Java source

Tags: android, proguard

I am using the code from **proguard-android.txt** file below

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

to obfuscate Android code.

**My Question** Does Proguard remove all the comments from the Java source file when we use the above settings in Proguard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ProGuard doesn't remove anything from the source files, regardless of settings. ProGuard makes sure that the *compiled* files have obfuscated method/class names and strips appropriate methods/classes completely when possible.

Compiled Java binaries don't include regular code comments whether you're using ProGuard or not.

Comment: Well, there's the semi-exception of [JavaDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) which is used to generate HTML API documentation (and can be distributed in a JAR). I'm pretty sure ProGuard doesn't do anything fancy to remove or trim down JavaDoc HTML.

Comment: @kabuko in my case all `JavaDoc` comments where deleted from the source code. I want to avoid that. Do you know how to?