# Keep method and fields description after obfuscating

Tags: java, android, proguard

I want to save all class/method/fields description (from which I generate JavaDoc). I have something like that:

```
/**
* description: example text
*/
public class ExampleClass implements ExampleInterface { 


/**
* description: example text

* demo: link to demo
*/
    public Object exampleVariable;
```

after obfuscating I got only this:

```
public class ExampleClass implements ExampleInterface { 
        public Object exampleVariable;
```

But I want to keep all the descriptions etc. This is how my `proguard-rules.pro` looks like:

```
-keep public class * {
    public *;
}
-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
    public static **[] values(); public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

What should I add to `proguard` to keep the descriptions?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356389/does-proguard-remove-comments-from-java-source/12356558) answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Proguard remove comments from Java source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356389/does-proguard-remove-comments-from-java-source)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that question already. The thing is it is not answered at all